# Python Save result as string

Tags: python

I was wondering if I can save my Python execution result as a string. I have tried Eval, Exec, and Compile and those were not the results that I wanted.

What I want is like it is below.

```
for i in range(10):
    print("Hello World! " + str(i))
```

For example, I have this kind of code here. The result of this expression is kind of obvious.

```
Hello World! 0
Hello World! 1
...
Hello World! 8
Hello World! 9
```

I would like to store this whole result as inside a string. Such as `hello_world_string`.
I kind of know that saving that first code part as a file and then executing it using Python by subprocess or similar function methods does return string type as their return values. However, I would like to know if there is any way that I can do this without writing into another file.

I am quite a newbie to StackOverflow. So I might have made some errors.
If so, please let me know. I will be happy to modify them as soon as possible.

---

Edit:

Sorry, I kind of made some mistakes in this question. I think the code up is not the right example of what I would like to do.

For example,

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40]
a.push
```

We have some error here at the example up.
The reuslt of this code would be

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'push'
```

I would like to save this output as a string.

The question seems to be misleading. I am deeply sorry for that.

**To be more specific, the Python Interpreter or Jupyter notebook "Prints Out" how codes went and outputs of each process. I would like to capture those "Printed Out" data as a string regardless of the code itself**.

Again, I am deeply sorry for making everyone confused. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think its a little unclear exactly what you want, and what your question is? Do you have an example of what output you exepct/wish for?

Comment: @KarlWilhelm Yeah, I think I  have made some unsuitable example for this question. I am editing the examples. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `subprocess` module. It will store the terminal output in a list. For example:

```
>>> import subprocess
# enter the command. For example I used "echo arg1 arg2" You can type your .py file directory...
>>> cmd = [ 'echo', 'arg1', 'arg2' ]
>>> output = subprocess.Popen( cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
>>> print (output)
arg1 arg2
```

Hope it helps ...

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make it as another file and run with subprocess! Think that would capture the output results!

Comment: Yes it will @Gooday2die. Subprocess is only for this purpose only! Please mark it as accepted or do let me know if it worked or not...

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple capture

```
exception_string = ""
try:
    a = [10, 20, 30, 40]
    a.push
except Exception as e:
    exception_string = e

print (exception_string)
# 'list' object has no attribute 'push'
```

Comment: Oh, I get what you are saying! I think I would be able to kind of use exception strings using your method. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but you could simply add the result to an initial string, and call the print method only once:

```
hello_world_string=''
for i in range(10):
    hello_world_string += "Hello World! " + str(i) + "\n"
print(hello_world_string)
```

Comment: Sorry, I have made you misunderstand the question. I have edited the question a little bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
hello_world_string=''
```

for i in range(10):
    hello_world_string += "Hello World! " + str(i) + "\n"
print(hello_world_string)

Output:

```
Hello World! 0
Hello World! 1
Hello World! 2
Hello World! 3
Hello World! 4
Hello World! 5
Hello World! 6
Hello World! 7
Hello World! 8
Hello World! 9
```

Comment: Sorry! I made some mistakes in the question that I have asked. I have edited the question a bit. Thanks for your answer by the way